# There is no row at position 0 Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server

In my Project I am retrieving some details from the DB storing it in Dataset and checking it in IF condition, I had put the breakpoint in the IF condition line and executed it to check whether it was correctly running, the Condition is Failing (i.e there is no row in the Dataset I had seen in the Data Visualizer also) but it is moving in to the IF block and the **Index Exception is Thrown** 
What could be the Error in it,

My code is,

```
string mac = GetMac();
DataSet dr = Namespace.SP.Storedprocedure(mac).GetDataSet();
DataSet ds = Namespace.SP.Storedprocedure(mac).GetDataSet();
try
{
    if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 || dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3)
    {
        string date = dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Date"].ToString();
        if (Convert.ToInt32(dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CID"]) != Convert.ToInt32(Session["CollegeID"]))
        {
            Messaging("This System is already Registered Under Different College.");
            getdet.Enabled = false;
            Register1.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (dr.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Mac_id"].ToString() == mac)
        {
            Messaging("This System has been Already Registered for Delivery on " + date);
            getdet.Enabled = false;
            Register1.Enabled = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Messaging("The Allowed Maximum Number of Systems has been Registered... ");
    }
    if (getdet.Enabled == false && Register1.Enabled == false && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Mac_id"] != mac)
        {
            getdet.Enabled = true;
            Register1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    ggvqpdetail.Visible = true;
    fillgridQP();
    foreach (GridViewRow gr in ggvdetail.Rows)
    {
        Anthem.Label lb = (Anthem.Label)gr.FindControl("lbl1");
        lb.Text = "Downloading";
        break;
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    lbltxt.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: on which line u r getting error while debugging???

Comment: Probably the first if statement after the try

Comment: the problem is your what ever is just empty

Comment: @ Anuj The condition fails in the First IF Statement but it moves inside the IF block and I am getting the Exception in the Firset line of IF block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Rows.Count is zero this line is always true

```
 if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 || dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3)
```

The `OR` logical opertator gives false for the first condition, but true for the second so the whole expression is `TRUE`.

Probably you need an `AND` logical opertator

```
 if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3)
```

but before this line you need to check for the rows count zero and take an appropriate action

```
 if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
 {
      // Operations for rows count == 0
 }
 else if(dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3)
 {
      // Operations for rows count <= 3
 } 
 else
 {
      // limits reached.....
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

your first if statement is doing the mistake,if you want the condition to be satisfied then you have to use `AND` instead of OR so that after both conditions are satisfied then you can enter the inner code of if block

```
 if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write

```
 if (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 || ((dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count <= 3) && (dr.Tables[0].Rows.Count >0)))
```

In your dr.Tables[0] may be no row is comming from database so you should validate it for row count.